# Visual studio code for CS50 asks me to reload over and over again

Tags: visual-studio-code, cs50, codespaces, github-codespaces

I'm doing the Harvard's CS50’s Introduction to Computer Science course and I've been trying to open my codespace in visual studio code for almost a month now, it used to work, but now it always tells me to reload the window, i reload it and the same error appears again over and over. I use chrome to open it and i'm on an imac.

I have tried:

- making a new SSH key
- making multiple new codespaces
- opening on the desktop version
- updating and rebuilding the space

Some other error messages that appear are (i removed the part where it says my address and user name):

---

Unable to open '**mycodespacenumber**'

Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://codespaces+ -code50- -/workspaces/ ' (Canceled: Canceled)

---

Failed to save 'settings.json': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://codespaces+-code50-/home/ubuntu/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/settings.json' (Canceled: Canceled)

---

Answer (score 0):

I face a problem that the Codespaces not even load. After 3 month It's work and load Normaly. If you still face same issue try to use CS50 IDE.

Or

Try with a new Github account.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33271049)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

This error message typically indicates that there's a problem with the remote server. The first step in troubleshooting this issue is to perform a restart. You can do this by visiting https://cs50.dev/restart. If the problem persists after the restart, you might find it helpful to check out the FAQs regarding CS50 Codespace at https://cs50.readthedocs.io/code/#faqs. These resources should provide you with more information on how to resolve this issue.